# Where do i need to put the break in my C# login?

Tags: c#

for a school project i am building a c# code with a login, multiple users and a database, but the problem is everytime i  login it shows the menu (partly) and it also
shows the login and  after 3 times, no matter good or false it exits the program my teacher told me i needed to break it somewhere, heres the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UserId
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Boolean loginOK = Login();
            if (loginOK)
            {
                hoofdMenu();

            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no, exit program");
            }
        }


        static Boolean Login()
        {
            Boolean loginOK = true;


             int MaxAttempts = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)


                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Type username");
                    String User = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Type password");
                    String Pass = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();

                    if (User == "ad" && Pass == "min")

                    {
                        loginOK = true;
                        hoofdMenu();
                    }

                }
                 while (MaxAttempts > 2);

            if (loginOK)
            {

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;


            }
        }

        static void hoofdMenu()

        {

            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello admin");
            Console.WriteLine("___________________________________________");
            List<string> menuItem = new List<string>()
            {
            "UserInterface",
            "Buying menuu",
            "storage",
            "Exit the Enivoriment",


            };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? It's a valuable learning technique to step through the code with the [Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) and try to predict what happens on the next step. If your assumption and reality differ, you should find out why. This way you should be able to find the right spot in your code to make your modifications.

Comment: What do you want to do if user typed in correct credentials on first appraoch? What if he did not provide valid ones after three tries? What exactly do you **expect** to happen?

Comment: You need to increment `MaxAttempts` inside your `do` block, so `MaxAttempts > 2` will eventually be true. e.g. `MaxAttempts++`. Actually it should also be `MaxAttempts < 2`.

Comment: `MaxAtemps` is never modified, it will allways be zero. So `MaxAtemps > 0` will never evaluate to true, making your `do`-loop executing exactly once on every `i`, so in sum three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just need a single loop that counts from zero to three. By "you need to break somewhere" your teacher ment if the credentials are correct, use `break` to exit the loop, even if you´re at the first iteration. So this should do it:

```
static Boolean Login()
{
    bool loginOK = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type username");
        String User = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Type password");
        String Pass = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        if (User == "ad" && Pass == "min")
        {
            loginOK = true;
            hoofdMenu();
            break; // <------------- see her, you exit the loop
        }

    }
    return loginOk;
}
```

Alternativly instead of the `break` you can also use `return true`, which will also exit the loop and return `true`.